# How to find current screen in cocoa objective c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, screen

I have multiple monitors connected to my system so how do i find the current screen   in my cocoa app. I Know [NSScreen mainScreen] returns the main screen but to get current screen is there any way.

Thanks in Advance !